# I need a customized Numeric keypad for mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, keypad

I'm developing a Hybrid App and I want my app to open a customized Numeric keypad that looks the same on all devices. Is there any AngularJS directive?

Comment: No, you have to implement it by yourself.

Comment: you need to show some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem before as I needed a consistent Numeric Keypad that looks the same on all devices and I ended up creating one.
You can find it on github:

[Code](https://github.com/firasiano/Numeric-Keyboard)

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/h3ag1KfJHxbFWYFj4DVQ?p=preview)

It's a module composed of

- Numeric Keyboard Directive which should be only one copy in the whole app, it's template is the actual keyboard
- Numeric Keyboard Input Directive, It's a clickable directive that opens your keyboard, you need to attach it to the editable element where you want your input to be.
- Numeric Keyboard Service, which handles the communication between the two directives.

`angular.module('numericKeyboard').factory('numericKeyboardService',numericKeyboardService);`

`angular.module('numericKeyboard').directive('numericKeyboard', numericKeyboard);`

`angular.module('numericKeyboard').directive('numericKeyboardInput', numericKeyboardInput);`